# Confused about which Library.... to use

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there are enormous library or API used with android HTTP Get,Post,Put.But can somebody tell me which library are better for get post and put and other various library

Comment: Aquery , volly and okHttp. Use any of them. Aquery is best as far as I know.

Comment: 1) retrofit 2) volley

Comment: Retrofit from square is my choice.

Comment: retrofit is great!

Comment: please accept the answers which you think is appropriate

Comment: visit http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use volley, it is the best thing out there, here I'm uploading some code to help you out.

**ApplicationController.java**

You have to add this file in manifest file's application tag,

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";
    private static ApplicationController sInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

        req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        ));

        VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {

        req.setTag(TAG);

        req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        ));

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomRequest.java**

Custom request to connect to database and get data.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import raghav.bookthat.support.Constants;

public class CustomRequest {
    static final String[] response = new String[1];
    private StringRequestCompleteListener stringRequestCompleteListener;

    public CustomRequest(StringRequestCompleteListener stringRequestCompleteListener) {
        this.stringRequestCompleteListener = stringRequestCompleteListener;
    }

    public static String getResponse(String response) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        if (jsonObject.getString("Error").equals("200")) {
            return jsonObject.getString("response");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void loadJSON(final HashMap<String, String> headers, final Context context, final ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        if (headers != null) {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.WEBSERVICE, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    try {
                        response[0] = getResponse(s);
                        if (stringRequestCompleteListener != null && response[0] != null) {
                            stringRequestCompleteListener.onTaskCompleted(response[0]);
                        } else {
                            if (progressDialog != null) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        if (progressDialog != null) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        response[0] = null;
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Wait\n The Internet is Quite Slow Down Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadJSON(headers, context, progressDialog);
                    } else {
                        if (progressDialog != null) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public Priority getPriority() {
                    return Priority.IMMEDIATE;
                }

            };
            ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

**StringRequestCompleteListener.java**

Listener to handle response of volley

```
public interface StringRequestCompleteListener {
    void onTaskCompleted(String response);
}
```

**Use of custom request**

```
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("method", "createBooking");
        headers.put("PackageID", String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("PackageID")));
        headers.put("UserID", String.valueOf(sharedPreferencesHelper.getUserID()));
        headers.put("Price", txtTotalPrice.getText().toString());
        headers.put("TotalPerson", edTotalPerson.getText().toString());
        headers.put("BookingStartDateTime", txtStartDateTime.getText().toString());
        headers.put("BookingEndDateTime", txtEndDateTime.getText().toString());

        final ProgressDialog progress = SupportMethods.showProgressDialog(context);
        progress.show();

        new CustomRequest(new StringRequestCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(String response) {
                progress.dismiss();
                if (response.equals("800")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Location Already Booked On Given Time, \n Please Select Any Other Time Or Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (response.equals("400")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occurred While Booking, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Location Booked Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityDrawer.class)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                    startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundUpdateService.class).putExtra(Constants.UPDATE,Constants.BOOKING_UPDATE));
                }
            }
        }).loadJSON(headers, context, progress);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

add ApplicationController to Application Tag

```
<application
        android:name=".support.volley.ApplicationController"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"><application>
```

Comment: for more information you can use this link

http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make requests to a database from your app, I recommand you to use the Google's library made for it : Volley

You can find tutorials [like this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800) which will permit you to make POST or GET requests.

You can also consult the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) of Google on volley

Comment: you're welcome, do you want more informations about volley ? Feel free to ask questions

Answer (score 1):

There are mostly tow library used with network relate operation like send receive data or request,response e.t.c, 
1) volley 
2) Retrofit

Both are good library and both are flexible and manageable library.

For Retrofit [Click Here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

For volley [Click Here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

Answer (score 0):

You used this for Http..
 httpclient-4.2.3.jar [Download Link For Httpclient-4.2.3.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient423jar.htm)

apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar [Download Link for apche-httpcomponents](http://%20%20%20%20[2]:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachehttpcomponentshttpcorejar.htm)

Comment: If anyone want to try through retrofit which provide better documentation of understanding http://www.iayon.com/consuming-rest-api-with-retrofit-2-0-in-android/